Exact sequence of Lie algebras
I'm trying to solve exercise 7.5.1 of Weibel's An Introduction to homological algebra. I need to show that there is a short exact sequence
$$H_2(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h},k)\oplus[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}] \to \mathfrak{h}^{ab} \to \mathfrak{g}^{ab}\to (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})^{ab} \to 0.$$
The action of $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ on $\mathfrak{h}^{ab}$ is given by the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\mathfrak{h}$ i.e. $g.h=[g,h]\in[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]$ whence the short exact sequence
$$0 \to [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}] \to \mathfrak{h} \to (\mathfrak{h}^{ab})_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}} \to 0.$$
Injecting that in the exact sequence of low degree terms, we get
$$H_2(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h},k)\oplus[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}] \twoheadrightarrow [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}] \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{h} \twoheadrightarrow (\mathfrak{h}^{ab})_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}} \to \mathfrak{g}^{ab}\to (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})^{ab} \to 0$$
which can be reduced to
$$H_2(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h},k)\oplus[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}] \to \mathfrak{h} \twoheadrightarrow (\mathfrak{h}^{ab})_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}} \to \mathfrak{g}^{ab}\to (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})^{ab} \to 0$$
by replacing the epi and mono by kernel and image. However, I can't seem to find a way to simplify this to get the result. Can anyone help me please? (Not necessarily the answer, just a hint would be good).

I don't know so much about Lie algebra (co)homology, but it seems like you're not really using the $H_2$ at all, right? It's just dying after map one. So I'm wondering if, despite the similarity between your sequence and Weibel's, this approach is just a dead end.

@hunter The last three therms are actually $H_1(\mathfrak{h},k)_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}},H_1(\mathfrak{g},k)$ and $H_1(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h},k)$ and the exact sequence is from the low degree terms of the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.

This exact sequence is proved in the paper by Hochschild and Serre from $1955$. The proof is elementary and you could just see there what you need.

@DietrichBurde What is the title of the paper?

G. Hochschild, J-P. Serre: Cohomology of Lie algebras.
Annals of Mathematics (2), 57 (1953), no. 3, 591--603.

@DietrichBurde I don't have access to this paper

Ask the library from your university.

@DietrichBurde I think you got the wrong paper, it's not in it. It only talks about cohomology, not homology.

There is an analogous version for homology.
